# How to Update a table on daily basic(static time) using unix script? automate the update statement

Tags: database, shell, unix

I have to update a table (X) on a daily basis. So I no need to run an update query manually. Can anyone suggest the best way to automate the Update statement ?

Comment: You can create a cron task which could be run every day executing your update script. Search on google about `crontab`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of `crontab` like below:-

Execute the below command

```
crontab -e
```

and add the below entry in your `crontab` scheduler

```
30 6 * * * /your/command
```

It will execute your sql command daily at `6.30 AM`. To change the time change first two fields.

Hope this will help.